# std::move() in function parameter does not do copy assignment?

Tags: c++

I read "C++ Primer", and I know that a function parameter will do copy assignment by default when pass to the function.

```
void test(string s) {
  cout << s << endl;
}

void main() {
  string s("123");
  test(s);
}
```

It can be understood as, when you pass `s` to `test(string s)`, it will do copy assignment first, then you can use `s` in the function, which scope is in `test(string s)`.

```
// test function
test()
{
  string s = tmp;  // the tmp is string s("123"); s will copy from tmp
  cout << s << endl;
}
```

My question is, if you pass an *reference* or *rvalue reference*, it will not do copy assignment anymore, right?

```
void test(string &s)
{
  s = "123";
}
```

If `s` does copy assignment, then you can't change `s` anymore. Is this correct？

Answer (score 1):

> It can be understood as, when you pass s in test(string s), it will do copy assignment first

There is no assignment involved in the fist example. The parameter is copy initialised from the argument.

> if you pass a rvalue .., it will not do copy assignment anymore?

There was no assignment involved regardless, but there will not be copy initialisation either if an rvalue is passed to the first function because string has a move constructor which would be called instead.

> or rvalue reference...

Depends on the value category of the argument.

---

In the second example you do copy assignment and in the third you use the assignment operator that accepts a pointer to char.

Comment: yes, I mean that when the parameters are passed in the function, the copy assignment will be performed, the you get an copy of the parameters. the second example is the explanation of below process.

Answer (score 1):

Using a reference in the parameter is a way to avoid the copy of the data passed into the function.

You can think of it as passing a pointer to the data instead of a copy of the whole data.
The difference with a pointer is that you avoid typing `t->xxx` and used it as a "normal" var `t.xxx`.

Another great difference with a pointer is that you can not pass a NULL reference. Sometimes this saves you a headache.

Now, if you want to preserve the original data and modify a copy of it inside your function, then the way to go is `foo(mytype mydata)` no reference, no pointer.

Finally, the `std::move` may be useful to avoid a useless copy. Many `std::` classes have a move constructor.